# SQL Server 2005 - How to find out what transaction log files have been restored

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, transaction-log

How can you find out what transaction log backup files have been restored using SQL in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try;

```
select distinct r.destination_database_name, r.restore_date, 
       bs.server_name, m.physical_device_name as backup_device, b.physical_name 
from msdb.dbo.restorehistory r
      inner join msdb.dbo.backupfile b on r.backup_set_id = b.backup_set_id 
      inner join msdb.dbo.backupset bs on b.backup_set_id = bs.backup_set_id
      inner join msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m on bs.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
```